# Стили для input css

Tags: css

Задал стиль для button:

```
input[type="button"]{
   ....
}
```

И хочу задать к другой `type="button"` совсем другой стиль, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input[type="button"]{
  background: #f00;
}
input[type="button"].btn{
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="button" placeholder="Text..." />

<input type="button" value="button" class="btn" placeholder="Text..." />
```

Comment: Помогло спасибо большое!